# why mvn doesn't generate fat jar

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

The following is my pom.xml, I want to build a fat Jar with command "mvn clean pacckage", so I have added a plugin, but unfortunatedly it doesn't generate a far jar, I only see a management-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, it doesn't contains any dependency jars.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xx.yy.zz</groupId>
  <artifactId>management-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>management-service</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>
  
  <build>
      <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
              </plugin>

              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> 
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Well you do not have any dependencies specified in your pom. The junit dependency is in scope test, so it will not be present in the jar

Comment: Your execution needs to go in <build><plugins>, not <pluginManagement> See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Declarations in `<pluginManagement>` do nothing actually. They are just a template what configuration should be used when actually using a plugin in `<build><plugins><plugin>...`.

Answer (score -1):

our execution needs to go in , not  See maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Is this a copy and paste of my comment, with the XML tags removed?